# SDL_RenderCopy() slow on Android

Tags: android, performance, sdl, render

I have the issue with performance on Android with SDL texture drawing.
90 calls of SDL_RenderCopy reduce FPS from 50 to 25-30.
If I call 1000 times SDL_RenderCopy I get 1 FPS.
A lot of calls I need to create particle system. But it is impossible with such performance. 
How can I increase performance? I can use only standard SDL functions without OpenGl.

Comment: I thought I had this problem, but it turned out when trying to write a mini benchmark that rendering was slowed down by my graphical debug text output using SDL_ttf (took 100ms).
Calling SDL_RenderCopy roughly 20 times is still below 10ms most of the time when reducing my debug output to one line, so it maybe is even faster.
Possibly related bugs:
https://bitbucket.org/DavidLudwig/sdl/issues/56/sdl_rendercopy-is-slow-on-windows-phone-8
http://bugzilla.libsdl.org/show_bug.cgi?id=3254